# How to run a javascript in side a javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to run this javascript :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[FANS='****'//]]>
</script>
<style>#fblikepop{background-color:#fff;display:none.....</style>
<script src='/facebookpop/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/facebookpop/mbtlikebox2.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script language='javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){                       
        $().FANS({
            timeout: 30,
            wait: 0,
            url: 'http://www.facebook.com/****',
            closeable: true     });
    });
//]]></script><div id='fbtpdiv'></div>
```

In side this JavaScript in the  "++++2nd JAVASCRIPT++++" position ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.cookie.search(/(^|;)facebookpopc=/) > -1) {
    return false;
} else {

    ++++2nd JAVASCRIPT++++

}
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.cookie.search(/(^|;)facebookpopc=/) > -1) {
    return false;
} else {
    $(document).ready(function(){                       
        $().FANS({
            timeout: 30,
            wait: 0,
            url: 'http://www.facebook.com/****',
            closeable: true     });
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
     if(document.cookie.search(/(^|;)facebookpopc=/) > -1) {
         return false;
      } else {                
        $().FANS({
            timeout: 30,
            wait: 0,
            url: 'http://www.facebook.com/****',
            closeable: true     });
         });
     }
});
</script>
```